# How to fix “Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt” error after updating android studio from 4.0.0 to 4.1.1?

Tags: android, github

I just updated my android studio for my group project which is on github which is using the same version(4.1.1), when I clone it it gives me this error and I dont know how to resolve it please help...

Answer (score 0):

Delete your wrapper file in gradle files and re download the gradle.
You will find the gradle file in C drive/user/yourusername